# Elevation extraction via 'elevation.clip' fails with 'CalledProcessError' using SRTM1 or SRTM3 in Python

Tags: rasterio, elevation, srtm

I am trying to extract the elevation data for a country and get an error with this code

```
dem_path = 'data/image_original.tif'
output = os.getcwd() + dem_path

bounds_combined = combined_polygon.bounds
west_c, south_c, east_c, north_c = bounds_combined
elevation.clip(bounds=bounds_combined, output=output, product='SRTM1')
dem = rio.open(output)
show(dem)


raster = riox.open_rasterio(output)
geom = combined_polygon

clipped_raster = raster.rio.clip([geom])

dem_path1 = 'data/image_clipped.tif'
output1 = os.getcwd() + dem_path1

clipped_raster.rio.to_raster(output1)

dem = rio.open(output1)
show(dem)
```

CalledProcessError: Command 'make -C /root/.cache/elevation/SRTM1 all ' returned non-zero exit status 2.

I tried with SRTM3 in the elevation.clip and still does not work

does anyone have an idea how to solve it?